# Is there a purpose for the long returned on the android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(...)?

Tags: android, database, insert, long-integer

I'm playing around with the SQLiteDatabase class and did't understand why the insert method returns a long since you cannot use it in any other method (delete, query, update) or am I missing something? What's is the purpose of this id long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the complete answer in this section from SQLite documentation http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Answer (score 3):

That long is the row ID of the newly inserted row. And yes, you can use it in `delete`, `query` and `update` methods. For instance:

```
long id = db.insert(blah blah);
db.update("table", aContentValues, "_id = "+id, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite stores INTEGER as 64-bit which is equivalent to Java long primitive type at also 64-bits.